# Which operations commute with fractional translation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, equivariant, sampling

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a real signal (i.e., an infinitely long vector).

A translation operation $T_{s}\mathbf{v}$ with integer $s$ is trivially
defined by $\forall i,s:\left(T_{s}\mathbf{v}\right)_{i}=v_{i+s}$.
We know that this operation commutes with convolution operations and
component-wise operations (not sure if these are the only operations though).

The operator $T_{s}\mathbf{v}$ with fractional $s$ is defined by
first interpolating $\mathbf{v}$ to the continuous domain by convolving
with the ideal filter $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc\_filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc%5C_filter)),
translating the continuous signal by $s$, and then down-sampling
back, i.e.
$$
\left(T_{s}\mathbf{v}\right)_{i}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}v_{j}\phi\left(i+s-j\right)
$$

This operation commutes with convolution operations, but no longer
commutes with component-wise operations.

**Question:** What is the set of operations which commute with $T_{s}$ $-$ for fractional $s$?